# How to display image and text from Cardview in another activity onClick?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-cardview, android-viewholder, android-recyclerview

I have a sample app from exoguru which contains cardview each card consists of an image and corresponding text .Now how to display that image and text in another activity on clicking that particular card?

Here is the screenshot [image]

Here is the ViewHolder which contains the onclick for the cardview

```
 class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public TextView tvNature;
        public TextView tvDesNature;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgThumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            tvNature = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nature);
            tvDesNature = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_des_nature);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

               v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(),FullInfo.class));

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the layout of the activity in which the image and text should be displayed

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="exoguru.lists.com.naturepics.FullInfo"
style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_card_title"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_card"

    android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_headline_material" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_card"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_card_title"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

These are the items from cardview

```
imgThumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);   //The image
tvNature = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nature);    //The Title
tvDesNature = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_des_nature);    //The Text
```

Comment: obviously you have to pass url to image/image/id of resource to the another activity

Comment: @Selvin yes,but how?

Comment: Why my question was downvoted? Care to explain.I asked a genuine doubt and there are not many questions to handle click of cardview layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the image url/id/.. on the Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("imageinfo", imageUrl);
startActivity(intent)
```

And on the destination activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String url = bundle.getString(“imageinfo”);
```